# When I click verify in email, how to make it go straight to android app installed?

Tags: php, android

When I click verify in email, how to make it go straight to android app installed

For Example:

Registration -> send Verification Email to user -> user clicks verification link ->
it will verify and echo "Click here to login" - > then it will go straight to the android app

Comment: what if i click on the link in my desktop mail application?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on verify link in the email it should take you to a link on your server. Based on the client request is coming from server should redirect it to appropriate link. If it is coming from mobile android browser server can redirect it to a page which is handled by your app with following intent-filter (and on desktop and other browsers you can just use different redirect page)

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data 
    android:scheme="http" 
    android:host="myapp.com" 
    android:path="/somepath/" />
</intent-filter>
```

See documentation for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html